# tcp сервер, метод accept постоянно принимает уже установивших соединение клиентов

Tags: python, клиент-сервер, tcp

ВОПРОС ПО TCP СОЕДИНЕНИЮ, НЕ ПО КОДУ!

Это выглядит так: сервер запущен, клиент также запущен, после чего accept производит соединение, а потом, через какое-то время соединение снова устанавливается с тем же клиентом или клиентами.

Также проясню я использую эмулятор для теста, эмуляторы подключаются через ngrok.

Я правильно понимаю, это так и должно быть? Ну т.е это обновляется соединение

Вот часть кода, для примера:

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 123))

server.listen(10) # тут можно указать размер максимальный для очереди из клиентов




connect_number = 0
arr_client_window = []
arr_clientCode = []
arr_client_info = []
arr_display_client_text = [] # так легче удалять клиента текст с экрана, просто по индексу


add_text_to_display('Working...\n')
while (True):
        
        global arr_client_window
        global arr_clientCode
        global arr_client_info
        global connect_number
        global server

        user, adres = server.accept()

        client_info = getSystemProperty(user)
        if(проверяю наличие клиента в списке по client_info)
```

Comment: Что такое getSystemProperty?

Comment: Ну и в любом случае нужен [mcve] а не непонятные обрывки псевдокода

Comment: getSystemProperty из названия это получить описание системы, т.е это запрос с командой для клиента предоставить сведения о себе

Comment: Вопрос не в коде, а вопрос по Tcp соединению больше, должно ли так быть? если да, я просто добавлю для этого обработку и вопрос закрыт, если нет - буду искать проблемный участок кода

Comment: Если клиент сам предоставляет сведения о себе, то из этого следует, что он может предоставить какие угодно данные, в том числе совпадающие с другими клиентами. А значит весь ваш вопрос не имеет смысла и связан не с tcp-соединениями, а с совестью клиентов

Comment: getSystemProperty - это команда для клиента, сам клиент лишь запрашивает соединение. Только команды вынуждают его что-то делать, а не он сам

Comment: В любом случае, в показанном вами коде нет никаких проверок tcp-соединений, и как следствие ваш вопрос не имеет смысла